# FunctionalTests for App Engine with the generated Cloud Endpoint Library

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gradle, integration-testing, google-cloud-endpoints

I have created an App Engine service that exposes a REST api. I created that with the Cloud Endpoint framework. One thing that this framework gives me is a java library that I for example can use in my Android app. That works fine.

What I want to do now is to add some testing of the endpoint. I would like to use the generated library to make calls to a running server. The Gradle App Engine plugin already support this by a build step called FunctionalTests. The only problem I have is that I have no idea how to access the generated library classes from my test. Anybody has done something like this?